# how to plot Y*X with a specified x-axis in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to use proc gplot to create a plot of my y-variable against response, but have a specific covariate(z) on the x-axis. Is there a way to do this in gplot? Ive tried y*x*z, y*x y*z, and a bunch of other similar things but can't figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Can you post a sample of what you want your graph to look like, as well as the code you've tried.  Are you set on GPLOT or can you use SG Procedures, e.g SGSCATTER?

Comment: sorry for the vague description. Basically, im trying to create the usual observed vs predicted plot, but I want this plot to have 'time' (which is one of my covariates) on the x-axis. Im not set on GPLOT, that's just my go-to as I'm new to SAS still.

Comment: Would you have two lines? Or three axises? I still don't see how you want the three variables to be displayed.

Comment: 2 axis,so it would have the observed y-variable on the y-axis, but time on the x-axis. Its possible i've misinterpreted the question, if this isnt possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a basic plot to me, I prefer `PROC SGPLOT` because its the easiest/clearest way to specify the X/Y. Assuming it's a scatter use `SCATTER`, if you want a line, use `SERIES`.

```
proc sgplot data=MY_DATA;
SCATTER X=TIME Y=PREDICTED_VAR;
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try